# How to loop an entire GridView having AllowPaging attribute set to true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a GridView asp server control in a page and I have set its AllowPaging to true. Now, I want to loop to the entire rows but it only iterates to the number of PageSize that I have defined.

Here is the asp code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvName" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
 List<string> list = new List<String>();
    for(int x = 0; x <= 9; x++)
    {
        list.Add("Name " + (x + 1).ToString()); 
    }

    gvName.DataSource = list;
    gvName.DataBind();

foreach(GridViewRow row in gvName.Rows)
{
    // gvName.Rows.Count only returns 5 instead of the total number of its record that is 10
}
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of answer.

Comment: What do you want to fetch? You can iterate the list for that information.

Answer (score 3):

That's a feature, not a bug, of how the paging works-- it only loads x rows for each page load.  Depending on what you need to accomplish, you could either:

1. Cycle through the rows on every page load (since you should only care about the visible ones anyway, right?)
2. Cycle through the actual data source, either using your *list* object, or *GridView.DataSource* (casting to the appropriate type first).

Comment: Hi dbaseman, I also want to consider the rows that are not visible on the page. Is there anyway I can handle that in the code programmatically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jemeel The GridView rows that aren't on the page don't exist yet ... what are you trying to do with them?

Comment: I want to navigate to those rows that are on the page that doesn't exist but It looks like it is not possible. Thank you for your support and answers dbaseman.

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid event `OnRowDataBound` event to do all the work you want with the rows

to get the count use:
    int count = list.Count;